# NavigationBar doesn't disappear after Show Detail segue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

Now I have a **viewController(A)** which is root view controller for Navagation Controller followed by Tab Bar Controller, I want to perform segue from it to another **viewController(B)**, totally replace the **A**.

Therefore I applied **show detail(replace)**, it worked well as what I think in other cases. However in this case, when **A** segued to **B**, the navigation bar and Tab bar still existed. Why this happened and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

In viewController(A) you have to write

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
}
```

and in viewController(B) you have to write

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}
```